# Roughly how many antitrust suits are brought each year in the US?

Tags: regulation

Of course it should vary drastically by year and especially by executive regime. I've done some googling and I can't really find even a ballpark for any period. I read that suits brought by the FTC are private, so I guess I won't find a list of specific cases, but I'd just like to know the general scale.  Are there any resources that could help me?

Comment: Ok this gives some information. https://blogs.wsj.com/cfo/2015/09/16/obama-antitrust-not-much-more-aggressive-than-bush/   I guess theres also a problem of not knowing how many actions were *threatened* and therefore deterred a merger even though no suit was ever formally brought. I guess I need to know more about this process before I can really understand the "scale" of antitrust measures taken by the government.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good resource from the Department of Justice exists [here](https://www.justice.gov/atr/antitrust-case-filings). The results I got from using that tool are below, using only the `Year` filter and counting the results.

```
1990 15
1991 17
1992 12
1993 11
1994 38
1995 54
1996 85
1997 66
1998 86
1999 87
2000 84
2001 47
2002 53
2003 50
2004 56
2005 52
2006 53
2007 58
2008 76
2009 62
2010 91
2011 110
2012 74
2013 70
2014 73
2015 63
2016 60
2017 32
2018 1
```

Some of those cases may include things that you and I may not exactly consider to be 'Anti-Trust' cases, but this at least gives a baseline you can use. For instance, there's 5 cases in the data set related to *[gun-jumping](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/g/gunjumping.asp)*, which may not be what you're looking for. The early 90s seem to be outliers, I'm not sure if this is because some cases weren't imported into the digital revolution, or if the Justice Department was less inclined to bring these types of suits in that time period or not.

Comment: It'd also be interesting to map this to amount of suits successful completed (to see if the higher numbers are due to excessive unwarranted filing, or actual valid trust busting)